# Printing a dynamic and large list in Python

Tags: python, list, printing, delay, subtitle

I am trying to print a large list like a sequence of charterers or subtitle in TV. I have attached the following photo to understand more:

[image]

And as you can see the input text should rotate from right to left.

To arrive at this point I wrote the following code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
from time import sleep

text = """A company which supplied lingerie to the Queen has lost its royal warrant over a book which revealed details of royal bra fittings.Rigby & Peller,
a luxury underwear firm founded in London, had held the royal warrant since 1960. It was withdrawn after June Kenton, who fitted bras for the Quee
n, released a book called 'Storm in a D-Cup'.Mrs Kenton said there was "nothing" in the book to "be upset about", adding that it was an "unbelieva
ble" decision.Buckingham Palace said it did not comment on individual companies"""


whole_Str = []
i = 0
while(i < len(text)):
    rest = text[i:i+50]
    i+=1
    whole_Str.append(rest)
for sequence in whole_Str:
    print (sequence, end ='\r')
    sleep(0.1)
```

However, there are two problems:

First, python editors do not allow me to over write different parts of this text on the same place.

Second and most important, I guess `sleep()` is not a reasonable solution to create a delay since for a large scale text, system should not stop to print just subtitles.

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: To clarify, do you want to print this to a terminal window?

Comment: By rotate right to left, do you mean like horizontally scrolling text?

Comment: `sleep` does not stop the system, it usually means the current process looses its CPU allocation for that period of time.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your first question is solved by this:

```
import sys
from time import sleep

text = """dummy text"""    

whole_Str = text

for i in range(len(text)-50):
    sys.stdout.write("\r" + text[i:i+50])
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sleep(0.1)
```

Not sure though what you mean with the second one.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work with the curses library. the code looks like this.

```
import time
import curses

text = """A company which supplied lingerie to the Queen has lost its royal warrant over a book which revealed details of royal bra fittings.Rigby & Peller,
a luxury underwear firm founded in London, had held the royal warrant since 1960. It was withdrawn after June Kenton, who fitted bras for the Quee
n, released a book called 'Storm in a D-Cup'.Mrs Kenton said there was "nothing" in the book to "be upset about", adding that it was an "unbelieva
ble" decision.Buckingham Palace said it did not comment on individual companies"""

def pbar(window):
    for i in text:
        #add a character to the string
        window.addstr(i)

        #refresh the window so the new character appears
        window.refresh()

        #sleep to get the scroll effect
        time.sleep(0.5)

#start the printing
curses.wrapper(pbar)
```

This is give the effect of a horizontally scrolling text that scrolls from left to right.